# Why thymeleaf link tag doesn't act like link just act like paragraph

Tags: html, routes, thymeleaf, href, spring-thymeleaf

The thymeleaf link is not working as a link

```
<a th:href="@{/greeting}">welcome greeting web page</a>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  When you view-source of the page in your browser, what do you see?  I'm guessing your Thymeleaf is not being interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

[Like this file structure you can use thymeleaf or any routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfBZ8.jpg)

Make sure to your html file is in the template folder of your spring boot Application